# Ubuntu 20.04 VPS randomly restarting with Cron Job

Tags: 20.04, cron, vps

I'm having problems with my VPS. It's randomly restarting, and according to the syslog, it's due to a cron job. I don't have any cron jobs running to reboot the server. It rebooted a bit over a week ago, due to again, a cron job. I have no clue why this is happening, and it's really annoying. I've used crontab -l and there's nothing but the regular webmin stuff. I've read that this could be a PSU issue, but however I just rent the server, I do not own it, so there is nothing I can really do with that. Any ideas of what could be happening? Everything is as up to date as it can, kernel version I think is 5.4.0. It's Ubuntu 20.04, the VPS is provided by Hostinger, and it's a 2 core 2gb ram VPS. I'm running a site and about 2-3 Node.JS apps on the VPS.

EDIT: On further inspection, I noticed something. The syslog says this

```
Feb 14 13:45:57 freshclam[455]: Sun Feb 14 13:45:56 2021 -> !Database load killed by signal 9
Feb 14 13:45:57 freshclam[455]: Sun Feb 14 13:45:56 2021 -> !Database test FAILED.
Feb 14 13:45:57 freshclam[455]: Sun Feb 14 13:45:56 2021 -> !Unexpected error when attempting to update database: daily
Feb 14 13:45:57 freshclam[455]: Sun Feb 14 13:45:56 2021 -> ^fc_update_databases: fc_update_database failed: Test failed (8)
Feb 14 13:45:57 freshclam[455]: Sun Feb 14 13:45:56 2021 -> !Database update process failed: Test failed (8)
Feb 14 13:45:57 freshclam[455]: Sun Feb 14 13:45:56 2021 -> !Update failed.
```

and then it starts ending a crap ton of sessions. Only thing that looks out of place was a bunch of error about Trust Issues, but those were appearing way before it restarted.

But, what makes me believe it's a cron job is

A. Hostinger has a "Recent Actions" tab, and it says "ct_reboot" was run, which these things only appear if it's a cron job.

B. In the syslog, it says

```
Feb 14 13:49:48 cron[167]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

I'm not sure if this means if a cron job was run to reboot, but this is what info I have.

I checked in `/etc/crontab`. Nothing out of the ordinary in /etc/crontab. `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` just spits out a bunch of `Stopped Session "insert more stuff here"`. Also Fail2Ban is set up and working.

Comment: Please show us the section of syslog output that leads you to believe it's a cron job. Click on [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1316439/edit) and copy/paste into your Question. Give us 5-10 lines above and below, too.

Comment: `root`'s crontab (different format) is `/etc/crontab`. Check there, too.

Comment: Examine `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` to see the end of the logs for the previous boot.

Comment: @waltinator I was in root. Nothing out of the ordinary in /etc/crontab. `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` just spits out a bunch of `Stopped Session "insert more stuff here"`. That's it.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Alright, will do. I will add what I said.

Comment: Maybe you could check out your firewall setttings with   sudo iptables -L

Comment: @mondotofu I can't really see why that would make the server restart, it's hosting a site and that doesn't really have problems.

Comment: You may have unwanted traffic interfering with your server that can be blocked by setting up some firewall rules given this is hosted in the cloud.

Comment: I have Fail2Ban set up, CloudFlare, and the iptables config looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked on freshclam. Its purpose is to update the virus databases with the latest definitions.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/freshclam

It can be set up as daemon process to update the virus definitions

You can do a ps -ef | grep to see if it's running.

It's also a good idea to find the freshclam.conf file and inspect the settings. Based upon the error codes, it wants to do the updates daily, but there could be a reason why the database update fails in this particular way.

Could it be a good idea to remove the database and or reinstall the daemon for freshclam?

Along the lines of messages on the cron running reboot jobs, I also found this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/883370/cron-running-reboot-jobs

which suggests that the message doesn't necessarily indicate a failure.  Go figure !

Comment: Thank you, this does look like it's not a cron job. I'm going to contact hostinger because this was only after they switched my server to a new one. I think this may be their fault.